# How to make image within a text respond to different screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I have an image that should be displayed on the bottom right, with a text that should be on the left side. it works perfect in the wide screens, but doesn't work in smaller screens
here is the part of my HTML code:

```
<hr />  
<div id="test">
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
  <p> some text here</p>
  <p>another text here</p>
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul> 
</div>
<hr />
```

The CSS code is:

```
#mainPage {
min-width: 450px;
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper { 
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 10px;
}
#test {
background:url('https://img.png');
background-position: right bottom;
padding: 0px 380px 0px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I have tried to add another div id after the 'test' div in the HTML file, and set content:url, and float: right. it has worked perfectly on chrome, but didn't work on IE nor Firefox!! I found that adding two divs after each other is the problem, and I am not allowed to remove the test div at all!!

Can anyone help me plz!!

Comment: A demo would be nice...

Comment: responsive layouts are not constructed with code such as you've shown here.  There are many resources on the web to instruct you in building a responsive page.  But Stackoverflow is strictly Q & A, so you won't find a tutorial here. If you run into a specific problem be sure to post it here.   Good luck.